# Setting Default Byobu screens

Tags: command-line, bash, byobu, gnu-screen

I've just installed Quantal as a fresh install, and want to set up Byobu as it was on my old system. In a previous version of byobu there was an option in byobu-config (via the F9 key) to create new windows which had a checkbox option to select if it was a startup option. The whole 'create new window' section of byobu-config is not there anymore!

I've tried adding the details of the windows I want to ~/.byobu/windows (below) but this has had no effect.

```
screen -t localhost bash
screen -t staging ssh dt123
screen -t fsuk1 ssh fs
screen -t php php -a
screen -t python bpython
```

Comment: (Not enough but an answer but byobu is now based on tmux, not screen, that might be why it doesn't work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Jorge Castro mentioned in a comment, the reason your `~/.byobu/windows` configuration isn't working is because byobu is now based on **tmux** (the "Terminal Multiplexer"). As mentioned by @Hai Vu, there is a workaround that allows you to use **screen** as byobu's backend, but it isn't overly complicated to switch to **tmux**.

You'll want to edit the `.tmux.conf` file located in your user's `.byobu` folder (`~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`). Here you will want to write commands to construct your terminal windows using the commands [found in the tmux manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tmux.1.html). Here is a simple example that can help get you started:

```
new-window -ad -n Git
new-window -ad -n "Project Build/Run"
new-window -ad -n PostgreSQL
```

Here I have inserted three commands into the `.tmux.conf` file. As defined by the manual:

> The configuration file is a set of tmux commands which are
>                      executed in sequence when the server is first started.

So in this case, when you start Byobu, you should see three pre-created windows with the titles "Git", "Projected Build/Run", and "PostgreSQL" (from left to right). Hope this helps.

Comment: There was a bug in older versions of Byobu up to 5.85 and you need to chain commands with a semicolon, see [my answer on SU](http://superuser.com/a/958965/252532).

Answer (score 3):

I found that if you run

```
byobu-select-backend
```

and choose *screen*, then it works. Selecting *tmux* as backend does not work. I am still trying to find out how to create windows with tmux backend. If I know how, I'll update this post.

Comment: `apropos byobu` for more useful commands. _tmux_ now is the default backend. BTW _F2_ creates a new window, _Shift+F1_ for help.